# Preimage of elementary Open Set $D(g)$ Tensor Product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes

Let $\phi: A \to B$ is ring morphism and $f: \operatorname{Spec}(B) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ the corresponding morphism between affine schemes. Let $g\in A$ and consider the open set 
$$D(g) = \{x \in \operatorname{Spec}(A) \vert g \not \in x\} = \operatorname{Spec}(A_g).$$

My question how to see that $f^{-1}(D(g)) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(B \otimes_A A_g)$?

My attempts:
$y \in f^{-1}(D(g)) \Leftrightarrow g \not \in f(y) = \phi^{-1}(y) \Leftrightarrow \phi(g) \not \in y \Leftrightarrow y \in D(\phi(g))$

Therefore I have to show that $\operatorname{Spec}(B_{\phi(g)})= D(\phi(g)) = \operatorname{Spec}(B \otimes_A A_g)$ but don't see how to show this.

Comment: I think $g$ is any element in $A$. Basically what needs to be shown is $B \otimes_A A_g\cong B_{\phi(g)}$.

Comment: Use that $B$ is an $A$-module via $\phi$ and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240060/localized-module-tensor-with-localized-ring